# Improve speed by creating dynamic columns in a Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am creating a Dataframe with the following information:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from time import time

start_time = time()

columns = 60

Data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(700000, 3)), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
Data['f'] = (Data.index % 60) + 1
Data['column_-1'] = 100
for i in range(columns):
    Data['column_' + str(i)] = np.where(  # condition 1
        Data['f'] == 1,
        1000 + i,
        np.where(  # condition2
            i < Data['f'],
            0,
            np.where(  # condition3
                Data['a'] > Data['b'],
                Data['column_' + str(-1)] * Data['c'],
                Data['column_' + str(-1)]
            )
        )
    )

elapsed_time = time() - start_time
print("Elapsed time: %.10f seconds." % elapsed_time)
```

**Elapsed time: 1.0710000992 seconds.**

I want to know if there is a better way to do it, generating the columns dynamically and improving the speed of the script, thanks.

Comment: That indentation is fun to read...might consider restructuring it.

Comment: You can use `numpy.select` instead of the nested `where` calls: `np.select([Data['f'] == 1, i < Data['f'], Data['a'] > Data['b']], [1000 + i, 0, Data['column_' + str(-1)] * Data['c']], default=Data['column_' + str(-1)])` Note, this doesn't really make it faster. Just way more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a profiler, you can see that the majority of the time is spent in `np.where`. Unfortunately there isn't much we can do about that right now.

The next-biggest time sink appears to be Pandas conversions, which are slow. So we can shave off some time making the code more streamlined (and more readable):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def make_data():
    data_raw = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(700000, 3))
    Data = pd.DataFrame(data_raw, columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
    Data['f'] = (Data.index % 60) + 1 
    Data['column_-1'] = 100
    return Data

def run1(Data):
    """ Original """
    for i in range(COLUMNS):
        Data['column_' + str(i)] = np.where( # Condition 1
                                                Data['f'] == 1,
                                                1000 + i,
                                                np.where( # Condition 2
                                                        i < Data['f'],
                                                        0,
                                                        np.where( # Condition 3
                                                                Data['a'] > Data['b'],
                                                                Data['column_' + str(-1)] * Data['c'],
                                                                Data['column_' + str(-1)]
                                                                )
                                                        )
                                           )

def run2(Data):
    """ Cleaned up """
    f = Data['f'].values
    a = Data['a'].values
    b = Data['b'].values
    c = Data['c'].values

    for i in range(COLUMNS):
        col = f'column_{i}'
        colm1 = f'column_{i-1}'

        colm1 = Data[colm1].values

        Data[col] = np.where(f == 1, 1000 + i,
                        np.where(f > i, 0,
                            np.where(a > b, colm1*c, colm1)))

%timeit run1(make_data())
# 1.31 s ± 101 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit run2(make_data())
# 1.22 s ± 26.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop
```

But we still are using `np.where` 3 times. Numpy functions are very eager, and `np.where` will end up looping over the data each time it runs.

So let's do better! We can "flatten" the whole thing and do it all in a single loop:

```
def run3(Data):
    def _run3(f, a, b, c, x, i):
        results = np.zeros_like(x)
        for k, (fval, aval, bval, cval, xval) in enumerate(zip(f, a, b, c, x)):
            if fval == 1:
                results[k] = i + 1000
            elif fval > i:
                results[k] = 0
            elif aval > bval:
                results[k] = xval*cval
            else:
                results[k] = xval
        return results

    fabc = Data[['f', 'a', 'b', 'c']].values.astype(np.dtype('int64'))
    f, a, b, c = [fabc[:,j] for j in range(4)]
    col = 'column_-1'
    for i in range(COLUMNS):
        colm1 = col
        col = f'column_{i}'
        x = Data[colm1].values
        Data[col] = _run3(f, a, b, c, x, i)

%timeit run3(make_data())
# 34.3 s ± 1.4 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Oh... never mind. This is what people mean when they say "Python is slow". Looping in C 3 times is 25x faster than looping in Python once!

So fine, let's loop in C:

```
import numba

@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def _run4(f, a, b, c, x, i):
    results = np.zeros_like(x)
    for k in range(len(x)):
        fval = f[i]
        aval = a[i]
        bval = b[i]
        cval = c[i]
        xval = x[i]
        if fval == 1:
            results[k] = i + 1000
        elif fval > i:
            results[k] = 0
        elif aval > bval:
            results[k] = xval*cval
        else:
            results[k] = xval
    return results

def run4(Data):
    fabc = Data[['f', 'a', 'b', 'c']].values.astype(np.dtype('int64'))
    f, a, b, c = [fabc[:,j] for j in range(4)]
    col = 'column_-1'
    for i in range(COLUMNS):
        colm1 = col
        col = f'column_{i}'
        x = Data[colm1].values
        Data[col] = _run4(f, a, b, c, x, i)

%timeit run4(make_data())
# 496 ms ± 70.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

And that's probably fast enough for today. + better algorithm - huge looping overhead = fast.

Answer (score 1):

Just noting that you're performing redundant calculations in your loop. This is impacting your performance. To demonstrate, I will switch to using `numpy.select` since it's easier to tell what's going on:

Initializing:

```
columns = 10
Data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(100000, 3)), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
Data['f'] = (Data.index % 60) + 1
Data['column_-1'] = 100
```

Timings:

**Redundant calculations**

```
%%timeit
case_f = Data['f'] == 1
case_ab =  Data['a'] > Data['b']
val_ab = Data['column_-1'] * Data['c']
for i in range(columns):
    Data['column_' + str(i)] = np.select(
        [Data['f'] == 1, i < Data['f'], Data['a'] > Data['b']],
        [1000 + i, 0, Data['column_-1'] * Data['c']],
        default=Data['column_-1']
    )
```

Results:

```
28.6 ms ± 1.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

**Pulling calculations out of loops**

```
%%timeit
case_f = Data['f'] == 1
case_ab =  Data['a'] > Data['b']
val_ab = Data['column_-1'] * Data['c']
for i in range(columns):
    Data['column_' + str(i)] = np.select(
        [case_f, i < Data['f'], case_ab],
        [1000 + i, 0, val_ab],
        default=Data['column_-1']
    )
```

Results:

```
16.1 ms ± 282 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

This results in a time savings of about 40-45% on its own.

Comment: I didn't know about `np.select`, very convenient. Interesting that this method is apparently quite a bit faster than row-wise iteration in Numba.

Comment: @shadowtalker I want to emphasize that I didn't use the same size dataset that was posted by the OP. Looking at the *relative* speed gain, they seem roughly comparable.

Comment: true, but the `np.select` solution still requires multiple passes over the data to compute the conditions for each case. So I'm curious to see how well it works on the original data set, and also how well it scales with number of rows and number of columns (which I haven't yet tested for the Numba version either).